# Insert new Row when a cell has a value within cells range

Tags: excel, vba

I need a macro to copy and insert a row below an existing when a cell had a value within a cell range, below macro insert a blank rows without coping cell value,

to be more specific, I need to when I fill in a cell within a range copy and insert a certain row below of it with this new cell value

```
Sub new-macro()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set rng = Range("F2:F12")

    For Each cell In rng
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

I found this script but it gives me "subscript out of range", any idea why plz?

```
Sub insertRowFormatFromAbove() 

Worksheets("Insert row").Rows(27).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To add (copy and insert) a specific row when you change a value in the range F2:F12 you must use the `Worksheet_Change` event.

You probably must adjust `Rows(1).Copy` to the row number you want to copy.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F2:F12")) Is Nothing Then 'if changed cell is within the range
        If Not IsEmpty(Target) Then
            Rows(1).Copy 'copy row number 1
            Application.EnableEvents = False 'prevent the following line to trigger the change event again
            Target.Offset(RowOffset:=1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown 'insert copied row
            Application.EnableEvents = True 're enable events
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

- I recommend you to read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Using `Select` is a bad practice and makes your code slow, so it is highly recommended to avoid it.

Comment: I actually got that script over the web, i'm not an expert or any near to as of VBA :)
if you have an idea of what i'm intending to get would you let me know plz?

Comment: @Ahmed Please read [ask] and update your original question, not in a comment (use the edit button below your question). All questions and code need to be in your question part. I'm far from understanding what your actual issue is and what your goal is, because now you are asking something completely different. Please be very clear and specific about what is your goal and what are your difficulties.